# Citation in caption*

Tags: citing

I would like to insert citations into my captions of figures and tables. I use two different captions and I will make an example:

I use

```
\caption{Title of caption that appears in list of tables/figures}
```

for the title that appears in list of tables or figures.

Additionally I use

```
\caption*{Source: Eidgenössischer Turnverein (1881), own illustration}
```

at the bottom of the table or figure in order to write the source of the table or figure. However, I would like to replace the above with

\caption*{Source: \tcite{turnzeitung81}, own illustration}

so that I get an actual entry in the bibliography which is not the case with simply writing the source as a text. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with \tcite inside the caption. How can I manage to make this work?

Here is the relevant code for my citations:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\newcommand\mycite[2][]{%
  \citeauthor{#2}\ (\citeyear{#2})\ifx#1\undefined\else, #1\fi}
  \newcommand\myfootcite[2][]{\footnote{\mycite[#1]{#2}}}
  \def\prevcite{} % initialize \prevcite
%% macro for in-text citation
\newcommand\tcite[2][]{%  
  \def\newcite{#2} 
  \ifx\prevcite\newcite 
    Ibid.%
  \else%
    \gdef\prevcite{#2}% update \prevcite
    \citeauthor{#2}\ (\citeyear{#2})%
  \fi
  \ifx#1\undefined\else, #1\fi}
%% macro for in-footnote citation
\newcommand\fcite[2][]{\footnote{\tcite[#1]{#2}}}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

Many thanks for your help!

EDIT:

Here a minimal example of the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}  
\begin{document}  
 \begin{table}[htbp]

    \begin{tabulary}
    \end{tabulary}

    \caption*{Source: \tcite{turnzeitung81}, own illustration}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{document} 



\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\biblio.bib}
  @Article{turnzeitung81,
  Title                    = {Statistik des belgischen {T}urnerbundes für das {J}ahr 1881},
  Author                   = {{Eidgenössischer Turnverein}},
  Journal                  = {Schweizerische Turnzeitung},
  Year                     = {1881},
  Number                   = {5},
  Volume                   = {24},

\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\biblio} % if you’re using BibTeX
```

Comment: yes, it didn't work.

Comment: A minimal example is needed, then, with also a minimal .bib file.

Comment: I just added a minimal example. I know it's not perfect. Please tell me what I need to add so I can do it tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: @MadJens: Are you also using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)? Note that a minimal example is something we should be able to copy-and-paste-and-compile and it should replicate your current setup... not a mix-match of code snippets. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and that's it.

Comment: ...as an example, your `\documentclass`...`\end{document}` segment doesn't contain a bibliography; your "`filecontents` bibliography is not complete as the bibliography item `turnzeitung81` is incomplete (missing a closing bracket); `\biblio` is not defined; `\mycite` is never used, neither is `\fcite`... and `\caption*` is not available, unless you add `\usepackage{caption}` to the preamble.

Comment: The problem is that a caption is typeset twice in order to see whether it is longer than the line width, so the second time `\prevcite` is always equal to `\newcite`. However, I wouldn't use "Ibid.” in a float, because you don't know where it will finally fall, so “Ibid.” could *not* refer to the last citation.